# Elasticsearch nested object filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and I am trying to create a filter to retrieve documents that have specific attributes.

The attributes are defined as nested objects in the mapping like so:

```
"attributes": {
  "type": "nested",
    "properties" : {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to perform a complex query in the form of:

```
(attribute.id == 1 OR attribute.id == 2) AND (attribute.id == 3 OR attribute.id == 4)
```

According to what I've read so far I've created the following query to es:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
     "query": {
        "match_all": {}
     },
     "filter": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "attributes",
           "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                    { "bool" : {
                      "should" : [
                        { "term": { "attributes.id": 1 }},
                        { "term": { "attributes.id": 2 }}
                      ]
                    }},
                    { "bool" : {
                      "should" : [
                        { "term": { "attributes.id": 3 }},
                        { "term": { "attributes.id": 4 }}
                      ]
                    }}
                ]
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
},
"sort": {
    "date": { "order": "desc" }
  }
}
```

However this doesn't return any results. If I remove one of the two `bools` in the `must` block it filters the documents correctly.

Same problem exists (no results) if I change the query (for testing purposes) to:

```
"must": [
  { "term": { "attributes.id": 3 }},
  { "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      { "term": { "attributes.id": 1 }},
      { "term": { "attributes.id": 2 }}
    ]
  }}
]
```

which to my understanding translates to `attributes.id == 3 AND (attributes.id == 1 OR attributes.id == 2)`

This is elasticsearch 2.x. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps each `bool` clause could be in its own `nested` clause? Instead of having it all wrapped up in one.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I will give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Can you post a sample document you expect to be returned by this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the results you are looking for, you will need to do two separate `nested` queries and link them together with a `bool` query.

Here is an example:

```
{
  "bool":{
    "must":[
      {
        "nested":{
          "path":"attributes",
          "filter":{
            "bool":{
              "should":[
                { "term": {"attributes.id": 1 }},
                { "term": {"attributes.id": 2 }}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "nested":{
          "path":"attributes",
          "filter":{
            "bool":{
              "should":[
                { "term": {"attributes.id": 3 }},
                { "term": {"attributes.id": 4 }}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The reason for this is due to a subtle nuance with nested documents and nested queries. Have a look at the part of the [documentation on nested queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/query-dsl-nested-query.html) that says:

> The query is executed against the nested objects / docs as if they
>   were indexed as separate docs (they are, internally) and resulting in
>   the root parent doc (or parent nested mapping).

When doing a `nested` query, you are not actually performing your query against the root document (though it *feels* that way). The query is operating against the nested documents *as if they were separate docs*.

Therefore, when you query for a *nested document* that has **both** id=(1 or 2) AND id=(3 or 4) you get no results. Each nested document, in your data it seems, has only one of these id values.

Comment: You are absolutely right! (as @EvaldasBuinauskas pointed in the comments above) What confused me the most is the fact that having a single should bool inside a must bool works.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really clear. Great help.